# Angular Material Expansion Module won't work

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to implement the first example of [Angular Material's Expansion Module.](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)

It is being displayed but not the way it should:

[image: expansion]

I assume that I've installed everything. Additionally I imported `MatExpansionModule`& `MatFormFieldModule`.

To install Angular Material I followed the official ["Getting Started"](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          Personal data
        </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
          Type your name and age
        </mat-panel-description>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="First name">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Age">
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                         (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          Self aware panel
        </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
          Currently I am {{panelOpenState ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
        </mat-panel-description>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
```

Comment: You also have to import `MatInputModule`.

Comment: @fridoo Still not working.

Comment: Can you show your imports and additional css you're using.

Comment: @fridoo No css, but I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: Did you try disabling `bootstrap`? Also did adding `MatInputModule` to your imports change anything? I think it has to do with `MatInputModule` because when you remove the `MatInputModule` from the `material-module.ts` in this [expansion panel demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qnddq) the result looks alot like the image you posted. If you then still have problems I would suspect that some other css code is interfering with the Material Expansion Panel, e.g. bootstrap.